# How to pass arguments to another module in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments

**module 1**

```
def x(options):
    code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--q', help='Search term', default='Google')
    parser.add_argument('--max-results', help='Max results', default=25)
    args = parser.parse_args()

try:
    youtube_search(args)
except HttpError as e:
    print (e)
```

**module2**

```
import module1

module1.x(agr1)
```

Trying to pass list as argument to module 1
**module1 is run from cli as**

```
python module1.py --q arg1
```

keyword should be from list

Comment: *"keyword should be from list"*.   What list?

Comment: module1.x(list) 

from the call function from module1

Comment: That does not enlighten me in any way.  `list` is a keyword.  Makes no sense in this context.

Comment: Additionally, you want to pass to a module.  Why?  Does the module care?  What will the module do?

Comment: consider list as a list variable... i will edit the question

Comment: there is a list of words in the listVariable, 

using cli manually we do 
python module1.py --q keyword

But i want it to automatically do it from another module

Comment: You want `parser.parse_args()` to work even if the module is not main?  Is that it?  This question is VERY unclear.

Comment: I am sorry, i am not able to make it clear!! 
Basically i am trying to "NOT" use the command line arguments from the command line.. Instead from another file.py

Comment: Instead of 
python module2.py arg1

I want to run it from another module module1
how do i pass arg1 from that module???

Comment: The reason you are not being clear is things like: `arg1`.  `arg1` appears nowhere in your question and yet you expect it to have some meaning to me?  You need to look at your question and edit it to be clear to what you are asking.

Comment: i have edited...